# How to send emails automatically when the cell value reaches 0 and the mail should be sent to the corresponding email id

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to tigger an email when my Data in Column G reaches "0" and the email should be sent to corresponding email and the content also should be corresponding the value 0.

[Please check the image for the data table created, In no.of months left column, now it is 9, but when it reaches zero, i need the message in H column to be sent to C column mail id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjQCn.png)

I am not to able write the code for it, so asking help

```
function SendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var sheet4=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
var monthsleft = sheet2.getRange(2,10).getValues();
var fullRange = sheet2.getRange("J2:J").getValues();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var p=sheet2.getLastRow();
for (var j = 2; j < p+1 ; j++ ) {
  if (monthsleft ==0){
var n=sheet2.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
  var emailAddress = sheet2.getRange(i,11).getValue();
  var subject = sheet4.getRange(2,1).getValue();;
  var message = sheet4.getRange(2,2).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: function SendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var sheet4=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');

  var months left = sheet2.getRange(2,10).getValues();

  var full Range = sheet2.getRange("J2:J").getValues();

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  var p=sheet2.getLastRow();

  for (var j = 2; j < p+1 ; j++ ) {

Comment: The variable `fullRange` has the values of `J2:J` but  `monthsleft` has only the value `J2`. Is that a particular reason for that? You don't use `fullRange` anywhere in your code. How do you expect to iterate over something that you don't use in the first place?

Comment: Can you  **update your original question** with a sample spreadsheet with the data? Can you also provide an example of the process how you would like it to be with the data before and after running the script? Also, please don't post code blocks in the comments, if you need, please update your original question. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Hi #iansedano I have updated the data for you, Please check and help me out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got that code from, you should generally cite the source of your code if possible.

### Issues with your code

- It makes reference to **two** sheets, whereas in your example there is only one.
- It uses the `PropertiesService` which is not relevant to your problem at all, at least you have not mentioned why it is relevant.
- You are not understanding how to use `for` loops. Please see [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) for them.

### Proposed solution

I have rewritten much of your code designed to run every Weekday at 9am.

First, replace your code with the following:

```js
function SendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // INSERT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // this gets all data in sheet
  data.shift(); // removes the first row (headers)

  data.forEach((row) => {
    var monthsLeft = row[6]; // gets number from 7th column (Months left)
    if (monthsLeft == 0) {
      var email = row[2]; // gets email
      var message = row[7]; // gets message
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Notification", message);
    }
  });
}

function createTriggerWeekday() {
  // Trigger every Monday at 09:00.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('SendEmail')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```

Then insert the right name of the sheet which has the example data you posted. **It should be in the same columns** or else it will not work properly. That is, Months left in column `G` etc. Test the function `SendEmail` by running it from the script editor. This should send the emails of all the lines with `0` in column `G`.

If this works, then run the `createTriggerWeekday` function to set up the [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

You can manage your trigger from script.google.com

#### Explanation and References.

- [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) - I used this method to get all the data in the spreadsheet into Apps Script. This way its much quicker and easier than making requests each time. It returns a two dimensional array with all the data.
- [`forEach`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) - to go over each row, I used this method.